# Own AlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

For my app, I want to implement my own AlertController. But I would like to have the same presenting behavior as the UIAlertController does: Make the whole screen a little darker with a translucent background and the alert animates in. I don't want it to appear with a modal presentation.

Ideally, I would like to present my AlertView like the UIAlertView with the present-method, e.g.:

```
let alert = MyAlertController(type: .example)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Edit**: Sorry, in my mind it was obviously clear what I wanted but reading the question again I see the issue... So here is what I've tried so far. I created a subclass of `UIViewController`, below you can see (shortened) code.

*Current Behavior*: When I present this ViewController, it just presents it in a modal way instead of darkening the screen and popping up my view. I know that I would need to implement the animations, but before I want to get to the

*Desired Behavior*: I can use my class in the same way as a `UIAlertController` (see above). I only need to initialize the Controller and then call present. How can I achieve this? It must be somehow possible I think since `UIAlertController` also uses the mentioned present-method. Thank you!

```
class FRAlertController: UIViewController {

private var alertView: UIView!


private var alertViewCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
private var alertViewCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


init(type: FRAlertControllerType, buttons: Bool = true) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    setupView(type: type, buttons: buttons)
}

private func setupView(type: FRAlertControllerType, buttons: Bool) {        
    setupAlertView()
}

private func setupAlertView() {
    alertView = UIView()
    alertView.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(alertView)
    alertView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    alertViewCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView!, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    alertViewCenterYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width
        , multiplier: 0.7, constant: 0)
    let aspectRatio = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertView!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: alertView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.05, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraints([
        alertViewCenterXConstraint,
        alertViewCenterYConstraint,
        widthConstraint,
        aspectRatio
    ])
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
}
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Instead of telling I want to do this and that, tell us what you have actually tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, now I updated my question and it got reopened. @AndreyChernukha

Comment: Now my question is more clear I hope :) @iOSArchitect.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present a view controller using custom animations, do the following:

1. Create the view controller that you want to present.
2. Create your custom transitioning delegate object (`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`) and assign it to the view controller’s `transitioningDelegate` property. The methods of your transitioning delegate should create and return your custom animator objects when asked.
3. Set the view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom`.

Call the `present:animated:` method to present the view controller.

References:

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)
[Nice example from Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2925473-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions)

Comment: Thank you, implementing a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` with an according `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` did the trick!